# How to configure spoon processors classpath in spoon-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven-plugin, inria-spoon

I am running spoon launcher in maven, but it is not finding the processors class path.

Maven debug statements:

> DEBUG spoon.Launcher - template classpath: []
>    INFO spoon.Launcher - Spoon version 7.0.0
>    INFO spoon.Launcher - running Spoon...
>    INFO spoon.Launcher - start processing...

When it gets to the last statement, it freezes and doesn't continue past that point.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>fr.inria.gforge.spoon</groupId>
    <artifactId>spoon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <processors>
                    <processor>com.xxxxxx.spoon.utils.RootElementAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                </processors>
                <processorProperties>
                    <processorProperty>
                        <name>com.xxxxxx.spoon.utils.RootElementAnnotationProcessor</name>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>classToUpdate</name>
                                <value>com.xxxxxx.rnaservices.Geocode</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </processorProperty>
                </processorProperties>
            </configuration>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please remove tag [maven-plugin]. You are not *developing* a Maven Plugin, hence it doesn't apply. Hint: You can always hover over a tag to see what it is for.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug. Would you open an issue on Github?